# Attempt to read or write protected memory when value to pointer

Tags: c++, compiler-errors

I have this code:

```
typedef struct {
    string fName;
    string str; 

}t;

//-------Other functions------//
void BeginTh()
{
    string arg = "yes";
    t *arglist;
    arglist = (t*)malloc(sizeof(t));
    arglist->fName = "comBomber";
    arglist->str = arg;
    _beginthread(startOver, 0, (void*)arglist);
    free(arglist);
}
```

And at 'arglist->fName = "comBomber";' i get this error:

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.AccessViolationException' occurred in <appname>

Additional information: Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.
```

Anyone can help me ? How solve this problem ?

Thanks.

Comment: You should be using `new` not `malloc`.

Comment: No offense meant, but this code is wrong and dangerous on so many levels, I wouldn't know where to start, You _really_, urgently, need to read [a good C++ book](http://stackoverflow.com/q/388242/140719).

Comment: Als: "You should not be using new nor malloc" FTFY?

Comment: @sehe: That depends.You cannot say that through the code that is shown in the Q.

Comment: Which language is this intended to be? It looks like C, is tagged as C++, and you seem to be getting a C++/CLI compiler error. So it seems like it would be in order to ask which language you *want* to write :)

Comment: @Als are you getting at preventing copy (see move semantics) or shared ownership (see shared_ptr)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One problem is that your `t` instance is not properly initialized. You can fix that by it by using `new` instead of `malloc` Your struct holds a `string`, whose constructor needs to be called. Calling `new` ensures that the `t` object gets constructed properly.

```
 t* arglist = new t;
```

then "free" the memory by calling `delete`:

```
delete arglist;
```

This points to the second problem, which is that your `t` instance must be guaranteed to be alive during the whole execution of the thread. You should not de-allocate its memory until the thread is finished. This is a C++ example where the `t` object is guaranteed to outlive the thread:

```
#include <thread>

int main()
{
  t arglist = whatever;
  std::thread t(startover, &whatever); // launches thread which runs startover(&arglist)

  // do other stuff

  t.join(); // wait for thread execution to finish

}
```

In general, Instead of using raw pointers to dynamically allocated objects, you should use a [smart pointer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smart_pointer).

As an aside, the `typedef` syntax for declaring a `struct` looks pretty strange in C++. Normally, you would do this:

```
struct t {
    string fName;
    string str; 
};
```

Comment: How would that solve his problems? The object will still be gone by the time the new thread is laying its hands on it.

Comment: @sbi thanks, I had completely missed that. Not being familiar with `_beginthread`, all I can say is "make sure your object is not deallocated until the thread is finished".

Comment: What? Why would it be unable to cope with user-defined types?

Answer (score 6):

I suggest modern C++ style:

```
#include <future>
#include <string>

struct arg_t {
    std::string fName;
    std::string str; 
};

int startOver(int i, arg_t args)
{
    return args.fName.size() + args.str.size() + 42;
}

int main()
{
    const std::string arg = "yes";
    arg_t args = { "comBomber", arg };
    auto worker = std::async(startOver, 0, args);
    return worker.get();
}
```

See it on http://ideone.com/zrXcwH (it doesn't run because ideone doesn't support the `pthread` library). I tested this with MS Visual C++.

If `arg_t` would be very expensive to copy, you can simply move it to the other thread:

```
auto worker = std::async(startOver, 0, std::move(args));
```

Comment: +1, but minor nit-pick: I think you need to pass `std::launch::async` to ensure the function is executed in another thread, otherwise it might just to lazy execution.

Comment: @juanchopanza YOu're right, i.e. if the goal is too mimic the original semantics. (On the other hand, this subtle difference might actually be _another big benefit_ of using the 'highlevel' portable interfaces)

Answer (score 3):

`malloc` will only allocate memory for object but will not call its constructor

you need change to new

```
t *arglist = new t;
```

Also, do not release arglist memory block before the startOver thread gets its content. you can release it inside the thread or somewhere else.

```
void startOver(void* param)
{
  Param* param_ = (Param*)param;  // get hold of param pointer
  while(true){
    // do something
   }
  delete param_;  // release param when thread finishes
}

void BeginTh()
{
    Param *param = new Param();
    param->fName = "abcd";
    param->str = "yes";
    _beginthread(startOver, 0, (void*)param);
 }
```

Comment: I am tempted to downvote this just because it shows `free()` as a possible match to `new`. Even though it's commented out, it _could_ give someone wrong ideas.